# What do the "d" in SDE notation mean?

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

An SDE is often written in the form $ dX_t=\mu dt + \sigma dW_t $.
What is the meaning of this equation in English?
If I had to construct an SDE, I would write something like $ \frac{dX_t}{dt} = \mu + \sigma \frac{dW_t}{dt} $. Why are SDEs not written in that way?
I know that the Brownian motion does not have a derivative so it has to do something with that fact but I don't get the real meaning of the standard notation.

Comment: I'd love to hear someone just explain the basic ideas of stochastic calculus in a simple way. Is there a notion of a derivative in stochastic calculus? If so what is it?

Comment: It seems that if you consider a  dynamical system subjected to the effects of noise, the "standard notation" is used as well:  http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Stochastic_dynamical_systems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An SDE is just a short way of writing the stochastic integral equation

$$X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t \mu ds + \int_0^t \sigma dW_s$$

So if we take the SDE form and integrate both sides we get:

$$\int_0^t dX_s=\int_0^t\mu ds + \int_0^t\sigma dW_s$$
With the natural equation $$\int_0^t dX_s = X_t - X_0$$ we get original stochastic integral equation.
So the SDE is nothing else then another way of writing the integral equation.

Comment: Why do we write $ dX_t $ for stochastic differential equations and $ \frac{dx(t)}{dt} $ for deterministic differential equations? I don't understand why we are only interested in small changes of the function values in the stochastic case.

Comment: $\frac{dx}{dt}$ means the differentiation from $x$ w.r.t $t$. But we don't differentiate $X_t$. You can read it as a differential of $X$ and then also in deterministic equations one writes only dx for the differential, c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function where you can find the explanation "In calculus, the differential represents the principal part of the change in a function."

Comment: Why do we not differentiate $ X_t $? Is it because $ X_t $ does not have a derivative?

Comment: To differentiate $X_t$ makes no sense. There are processes $X_t$ which solves SDEs but are almost surely nowhere differentiable, e.g. a brownian motion which solves the simple SDE $$dX_t = dW_t$$