# Some place from the proof of the Ito representation theorem

Tags: stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

I have read Bernt Oksendal's "Stochastic Differential Equations", and I stuck at such moment from the proof of the Ito representation theorem on the page 52, so he says :

> Define
> $$Y_t(\omega) = \exp\left\{\int_0^t h(s)dB_s(\omega) - \frac12\int_0^th^2(s)ds\right\};\ \ 0\le t \le T. $$
> Then by Itô's formula
> $$ dY_t = Y_t(h(t)dB_t - \frac12 h^2(t)dt) + \frac12Y_t(h(t)dB_t)^2 = Y_th(t)dB_t  $$

I cant get it, how did he use Ito's formula (lemma) here? I tried to simply write down partial derivatives by $t$, $x$ and $x^2$ from Ito's formula, but I can't get $h(t)dB_t$ element. For $dB_s$ in integral I used such formulas as
$$\int_0^t f(s)dB_s = f(t) B_t - \int_0^t B_sdf_s $$

Also I used [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) but it didn't help.

So, I would really appreciate, if someone would painted steps of how we got output of this $dY_t$ derivative.

Comment: please avoid using images to display equations and [use MathJaX instead](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: You are right, I appreciate your notice, next time I will try to do this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just notice that $Y_t$ is given by $Y_t \equiv e^{Z_t}$ where $Z_t$ is a solution of the SDE

$$dZ_t = h(t)dB_t - \frac12 h^2(t) dt .\tag1$$

Hence you can apply Itô's lemma to $f(t,Z_t) := e^{Z_t}$ as follows :

$$\begin{align*}dY_t = df(t,Z_t) &= f_t (t,Z_t) dt + f_x(t,Z_t)dZ_t + \frac{1}{2}h(t)^2f_{xx}(t,Z_t)dt\\
&= 0 + e^{Z_t}dZ_t + \frac{1}{2}h(t)^2 e^{Z_t}dt
\end{align*}$$

Now replace $e^{Z_t}$ by $Y_t$ and $dZ_t$ by its expression given in $(1)$ and conclude.

Comment: How did you got it? Namely that is the case, here you just made from big question question smaller than big, but the question is staying - how to find partial derivative of Z by t, x, x^2 in this case? If it's more simple, you can give me hint with it, I will also glad to it.

Comment: I just added more details to my answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I mean I understand how to do solution having that Zt is solution of particular SDE, but my question is how to show it? How to show, that Zt is solution of SDE, mentioned above?

Comment: ? That's the literal definition of $Z_t$. When we write for a process $X_t$ that $X_t$ is solution of 
$$ dX_t = \mu dt + \sigma dB_t $$
it's just a short-hand notation to say that
$$X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t \mu (s) ds + \int_0^t \sigma(s) dB_s $$
See [What do the "d" in SDE notation mean ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3659675/857384) if you're not clear on that. (I'm pretty sure Oksendal discusses that in his book too)

Comment: Wait, I know the equation for the process Xt (through dXt), my question is, where did you know, that μ will be -(1/2)h^2 and that σ will be h?

Comment: I'm sorry I fail to see what you don't understand... $Z_t$ is by definition (ie page 52 of Oksendal you cite) given by
$$Z_t := \int_0^t h(s) dB_s -\frac12\int_0^t h(s)^2 ds $$
As I just said above, we can write it in differential notation as
$$dZ_t = h(t)dB_t - \frac12 h^2(t) dt $$
So if you like we just identify $\mu(t) \equiv -\frac12  h^2(t)$ and $\sigma(t) \equiv h(t)$... Is that what you were asking ?

Comment: Okay, I just cant understand, how do we integrate both parts with respect to variables, that have unclear relationships (for example Bs and Xt). as far as I remember it right, to integrate both parts we need relationship between vartiables, that will be integrated

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to solve each integral 
$$\int_0^t h(s)dB_s\ \text{ and }\ \int_0^t h^2(s) ds ? $$
The point is that we **don't**, we apply Itô's lemma and we find the SDEs solved by the corresponding processes. That seems to be beyond the scope of your original question, and as this exchange is getting long, if you have more doubts please ask a separate, specific question.

Comment: No, I cant see intuition beyond integrating both sides, which have different integration variables.

Comment: and I'm telling you that's not the point of your original question, which was to prove that $dY_t = Y_t h(t) dB_t$. Processes of the form $\int_0^t \mu(s) ds + \int_0^t \sigma(s) dB_s$ are called [Itô processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus#It%C3%B4_processes) and are at the core of stochastic calculus. We don't solve for the integrals in close form because it is not tractable in most cases and because these quantities are random, we are mostly interested in their distributions, which we can recover even when written in integral form.

Comment: okay i will ask separate question

Comment: I cant get from your answer, how did you find derivative of f by t(or derivative of f by x and by x again)? Last element, 1/2*h^2*e^Z, where did you get it from? And what is 0?

Comment: Well, $f(t,x) := e^x$ so $f_t(t,x) = 0$ and $f_x(t,x) = f_{xx}(t,x) = e^x$

Comment: So Zt doesnt depend on t?

Comment: $Z_t$ depends on $t$ in some sense, yes, but when you apply Itô's lemma you directy plug in the expressions of $f_t, f_x$ and $f_{xx}$ and apply them to $(t,Z_t)$, so the dependence of $Z_t$ on $t$ does not affect the result.

Comment: Just I cant get it, how can it be, that derivative of Zt by t will be 0, when Zt depends in some sense on t...

Comment: The derivative of $Z_t$ with respect to $t$ is **not** involved in any of this (you know that the sample paths of Itô processes are not differentiable, right ?). This is not calculus in the usual sense ! What Itô's lemma tell you is that you can compute the partial derivatives of $f$, and plug in your process $Z_t$ to compute the differential of $f(t,Z_t)$. So it allows us to extend the notion of differentiation to quantities which are not differentiable in the usual, real analysis sense, that's the one of the main points of stochastic calculus I would say

Comment: You seem very confused about some basics about Itô's lemma, so I strongly suggest you to have a read at this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma#Examples) and work through the examples **by doing all the computations yourself**. I also advise you to go back to the earlier chapter Oksendal's book which you are currently reading and make sure you really understand all the fundamentals. After that, if you still have trouble applying/understanding Itô's lemma, feel free to ask a separate question. This is not what the comment section is made for.

Comment: In example of Geometrical Brownian motion, from the link, that you sent me, really, f depends only on St, so I dont have any question about that. But in our case, it also depends on t through h(t), am I wrong... Okay, I will read once again previous paragraphs, but I have already done it recently, but okay

Comment: Please ask a separate question.